# How to mock a call to __next__

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, mocking

I am trying to mock a coroutine. As such, this mock's `__next__()` and `close()` are called. While mocking `close()` works, I cannot mock `__next__()`:

```
    mock_coroutine = mock.Mock()
    mock_coroutine.some_call(1, 2, 3)
    mock_coroutine.some_call.assert_called_with(1, 2, 3)
    mock_coroutine.close()
    mock_coroutine.close.assert_called_with()
    #this fails
    mock_coroutine.__next__()
    mock_coroutine.__next__.assert_called_with()
```

What am I missing? How to make sure my mock's `__next__()` method is called?

For now, I am using the following:

```
class MockCoroutine:
    def __next__(self):
        self.called_next = True

    def close(self):
        self.called_exit = True
```

However, I very much rather use a standard mock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `MagicMock`, not `Mock`, to have magic methods like `__next__` available by default:

```
>>> from unittest import mock
>>> mock_coroutine = mock.MagicMock()
>>> mock_coroutine.__next__()
<MagicMock name='mock.__next__()' id='4464126552'>
>>> mock_coroutine.__next__.assert_called_with()
```

Quoting from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide):

> `Mock` allows you to assign functions (or other `Mock` instances) to magic methods and they will be called appropriately. The `MagicMock` class is just a `Mock` variant that has all of the magic methods pre-created for you (well, all the useful ones anyway).

So, alternatively, you could still use the regular `Mock` object, but then you need to explicitly add that attribute:

```
>>> mock_coroutine = mock.Mock()
>>> mock_coroutine.__next__ = mock.Mock()
>>> mock_coroutine.__next__()
<Mock name='mock.__next__()' id='4464139232'>
```

That's because although `Mock` creates attributes on the fly as you access them, any attributes with leading and trailing underscores are explicitly exempted from that. See [this footnote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id3):

> The only exceptions are magic methods and attributes (those that have leading and trailing double underscores). Mock doesn’t create these but instead raises an `AttributeError`. This is because the interpreter will often implicitly request these methods, and gets very confused to get a new Mock object when it expects a magic method. If you need magic method support see [magic methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#magic-methods).

But note that the magic methods are usually meant to be looked up *on the class, not the instance*, so directly adding the `__next__` attribute to a `Mock` instance can still fail; the `MagicMock` class takes care of this specific issue for you.